# How do i get a subString?

Tags: ios, string, swift, substring

Could someone pls tell me how i get a subString from a String? I tried everything with substring and rangeOfString methods but can't solve it...
My text goes like this:

```
var text = "Suuuuper, {1} has sent {2} a very cool present"
```

My text can vary before {1} and after {2}, so I suppose I have to first get always the indexes of "{1}" and "{2}" and then get substrings.

I would like to have in the end:

```
var myTextBefore{1}: String = ...

var myTextAfter{2}: String = ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I tried everything with substring and rangeOfString methods` - Can you show us these efforts? Maybe we can point out what's wrong with them.

Comment: {1} and {2} what are they, it will be like this or it will replace with some names? iwhat will be the format will it be like {name1} or name1?

Comment: Just a side note: This looks like your trying to input some names into a notification body. Why not just use a formatted string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rangeOfString`, `substringToIndex` and `substringFromIndex` methods:

```
let text = "Suuuuper, {1} has sent {2} a very cool present"
let myTextBefore1 = text.substringToIndex(text.rangeOfString("{1}")!.startIndex) // "Suuuuper, "
let myTextAfter2 = text.substringFromIndex(text.rangeOfString("{2}")!.endIndex) // " a very cool present"
```

Comment: Thanks man, that solved it!!!